# SproutCore/Cappuccino/Vaadin: which one should I choose to execute shell programs?

Tags: web-applications, vaadin, sproutcore, cappuccino

I've a command line tool I've written in some language and I like to build a web interface upon it. Can SproutCore run such a program and take the output?

I'm also taking in consideration other alternatives like Vaadin or Cappuccino (since I come from Mac development).

(I'm a software developer, I never developed for the web, and I found those 2 names googling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin can definitely can do that.

Both SproutCore and Cappucino are browser-side frameworks for developing the UI, and have no server-side portion to run the command - so you'd probably need to use a different framework on the server too.

**However** : all of these frameworks seem like a huge overkill for what seems like a simple task. How complex is the user interface you wish to develop? how "interactive" is it? How much maintenance/development is it going to need?

Comment: The web app is not so simple. Via some menus, checkbox and textfield (organized in tabs) I'd like to choose the parameters to pass to the shell program. Then I'd like to store the results for each user, show some plots

Comment: and I don't mind about speed, I just want to build this web app without learning html/css and stuffs like that (I'm a software developer). Hopefully with a tool to develop the user interface visually.

Comment: You can avoid html and css a lot by using Vaadin. It is a java web application framework : you will have to know/learn java. If the standard look and feel is not appropriate, you will have to get your hands dirty in CSS.

Comment: Oh : and "develop the user interface visually" - there is a visual editor for Vaadin, but I've never used it.

Comment: Well, for me, it would be : I am a java developer. If you're not, it might not be.

Comment: Of course, it should be noted - I am an active Vaadin user, and so am biased towards it.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that as you do come from a Cocoa programming background, you will feel right at home with Cappuccino. To make the interface, you will be using no other than the embedded Interface Builder inside Xcode4.

Also, as you don't want to learn any HTML/CSS to do so, and I assume that you dont want to do Java either, you can have a look at it.

Cappuccino is at 0.9.6 but it has been production ready for quite some time now. I think when it was 0.8 it was ready.

There are a lot of frameworks and categories available for Cappuccino and the google group is really helpful

Comment: but Charles Anthony said it's not possible with Cappuccino to run shell programs.

Comment: @taurus you can run a simple node.js app which can run the shell programs for you.

Comment: I've Xcode 4.5.2 and if I install Cappuccino, I can't see the templates in Xcode. Btw by node.js you mean http://nodejs.org?

Comment: @taurus I too have Xcode 4.5.2 installed. The easiest way to see and create a new cappuccino app is from the terminal. `capp gen --list-templates` will give you a list of templates. The usual output should be Application, Framework, NibApplication, ThemeDescriptor.  Then you can use the following command to generate a new application. `capp gen -t <templateName> <appname>`

Comment: @taurus Yes, by Nodejs I meant nodejs.org. It is Javascript on the server.